# periodicity within Signal

Tags: time-series, signal-processing, signal-detection

I am actually measuring the current of a dc motor, it takes values between, and I want to be able to find periodic peaks within my signal.
 My motor is connected to a spindel, the goal is to detect any problems linked to it, since if the spindel isnt corretly mounted the current will take a silight peak then go back to normal, for each period.
I have used the FFT, but due some problems with the sampling rate, i have been looking for other methods. any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

An FFT should "work" on data sampled at any sampling rate as long you're not bumping into the [Nyquist limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency).

Although *most* FFT implementations assume that their input data is regularly spaced (i.e., sampled at a fixed sampling rate), there are algorithms that exist for fourier transforming irregularly-spaced data. These are sometimes called NUFFT (for non-uniform FFT) or NFFT.

[This thread](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/593/how-do-i-take-the-fft-of-unevenly-spaced-data) on SciComp has some useful pointers, and this paper by [Greengard and Lee](http://math.nyu.edu/faculty/greengar/glee_nufft_sirev.pdf) describes an implementation and has pointers to related work. In brief, they convolve the data with a Gaussian to smear it out onto a very fine grid, run an FFT on the now-regularly-spaced data, and then deconvolve it.

Comment: My pleasure. If you can edit your question to make the data analysis issues a bit clearer, I'd be happy to expand it. All I really had to go on here was that you had issues with the sampling rate and, per my answer, I don't think that should stop you from using an FFT, assuming you're not trying to detect a 10 Hz oscillation in a signal sampled at 1 Hz or something like that.